# Can the cyclic permutation of a specific situation always be solved in reference to its linear variant? Why?

Tags: combinatorics

My answer to this is no. But I am after the explanation on why this is so. Also, when is it suppose to be equivalent to each other.

Let us say there are 6 people that have to sit in 6 chairs.

Values

- Number of ways they can sit without restriction: 6! = 720
- Number of ways two specific people can sit together: 2! * 5! = 240
- Number of ways two specific people cannot sit together: 6! - 2! * 5! = 480

Computing the cyclic versions traditionally:

- Number of ways they can sit without restriction: (6-1)! = 120
- Number of ways two specific people can sit together: 2! (5-1)!  = 48
- Number of ways two specific people cannot sit together: (6-1)! - 2! (5-1)! = 72

Let me try to do that by using the concept that the cyclic permutation of a specific arrangement is equal to its linear variant divided by the number of slots.  But I would like for someone knowledgeable to explain to me why is it that it works in some cases and it doesn't for others without just resorting to plain intuition. I want to make a generalization.

Computing the cyclic versions based on linear values

- Number of ways they can sit without restriction: 720 / 6 = 120
- Number of ways two specific people can sit together: 240 / 5 = 48
  With two people that have to be together, the slots have become 6 - 1 or 5.
- Number of ways two specific people cannot sit together: Yeah this won't work out. You can't divide 480 by any integer to make it 72.

Why is it so? Yes, I know that linear and cyclical events are not really stated in any textbook to have this general relationship. I just made it because it worked in some cases.

I do believe linear and cyclic events have that relationship if their values are not obtained by simply subtracting the sample space from their complement, based from what I have shown. I just need confirmation if this is true.

Intuitively, you can say that the linear and cyclic permutations do not correspond because you can place the two people at both ends of the six chairs and when you put them in a circle they are gonna be beside each other.

My intention for this question is to be able to make a generalization that for "this situation" the linear and cyclic permutations can correspond to each other. So if something complicated pops up, I could solve for the linear permutation method first and then simply divide it by the number of slots which do already depend on the problem as you have seen by 6 changing to 5.

As you know, problems like these come with really weird situations like two people having to be together or not, groups of people, alternating genders and the like.

Comment: i cant understand your question properly,$720=6!$ and $6!/6=5!$ exactly how they specify in tectbooks.........if your question is why we are dividing by 6 here,it is becouse in cyclic permutations donot have a starting and ending point.

Comment: I mean for the third case, we can't do 480 divided by 5 or by any integer for that matter to get 72. I want to know, what specific instance of linear permutations does dividing allow it to become the cyclical variant and when does it not and you have to resort to other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

The third part can be thought of this way:

keeping aside the two people who do not want to be seated together we arrange the remaining 4 people linearly in 4! ways. now if they are to be seated around a circle we divide it by 4(as there is no starting point in a circle). we get $\frac{4!}{4}=3!$

these 4 people create 4 gaps along the circle and we select two gaps among those to seat the remaining 2 people in $\binom{4}{2}.2!$ ways.
total no. of ways = 3!.$\binom{4}{2}.2!$ = 72

there is no general way of converting any linear permutation to cyclic permutations directly(that i know of).

Comment: I get that there isn't a general way, but it works on select cases. Can't it be divided into two cases: one where it works and one where it does not? Does each category have characteristics in common so that for solving people can rely on the idea of "Can this be converted or not?" for the solution?
It does work in the first two situations above
1) No restriction
2) Two people have to be together

Comment: @AndroidV11 the types of questions are too vast to categorize them. it is better to treat each question individually.